# How can I center a frame in GridSpec?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, centering

How can I center an image in a GridSpec divided frame? I've got the below image, and I want to have the upper picture to be centered.

[image: Picture to be centered]

The relevant code (part of it, especially the units, is from the [AMUSE](http://www.amusecode.org) framework) :

```
lim = [-5,5] | units.kpc
bins = [100,100]
xyrange = [[-5,5],[-5,5]]
cmap = cm.jet

hist2d_xy,_,_ = np.histogram2d(particles.x.value_in(units.kpc),particles.y.value_in(units.kpc),bins=bins, range=xyrange)
hist2d_xz,_,_ = np.histogram2d(particles.x.value_in(units.kpc),particles.z.value_in(units.kpc),bins=bins, range=xyrange)

maximum_value = max([hist2d_xy.max(),hist2d_xz.max()])

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[3,1])
ax1 = pyplot.subplot(gs[0])


pyplot.imshow(np.flipud(hist2d_xy.T),cmap=cmap,extent = np.array(xyrange).flatten(), interpolation='none',norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1,vmax=maximum_value))
cbar = pyplot.colorbar()

ax2 = pyplot.subplot(gs[1])
pyplot.imshow(np.flipud(hist2d_xz.T),cmap=cmap,extent = np.array(xyrange).flatten(), interpolation='none',norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1,vmax=maximum_value))
pyplot.ylim([-1,1])
cbar = pyplot.colorbar()
pyplot.tight_layout()
pyplot.savefig(file_location_for_pictures+'test_%.2f.png' %threshold)
pyplot.close()
```

Comment: Make a 3x2 grid, have the bottom one span all three and the top one only use the middle.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

Comment: I use `subplot2grid()`, but the upper picture is too small then. But thanks for the link, `subplot2grid()` seems very handy.

Comment: @tcaswell I did it, but with a 6x6 grid, and using 4x4 (with a (0,1) offset) for the upper, and 2x6 for the lower one. Thanks!

Comment: Please write up what you did as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[3,1])
ax1 = pyplot.subplot(gs[0])

ax2 = pyplot.subplot(gs[1])
```

with

```
ax1 = pyplot.subplot2grid((6,6), (0,1), colspan = 4, rowspan = 4)

ax2 = pyplot.subplot2grid((6,6), (4,0), colspan = 6, rowspan = 2)
```

(at the right place), and it now produces this picture (edited colors and added some text, but the idea is clear):

[image: Centered upper picture]